# MySQL: Get Count of rows and add specific value to total count from each row

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

[image]

I need to count every row where tblEventID is 32. So the result will be 3. (easy aggregate function):

```
SELECT COUNT(status) FROM ...
```

BUT:

I need to also add the value in column `plusOnes` to the overall.

So the result must be 3 (count) + 2 + 2 + 0 = 7.

Meaning I have to look at each row individually, add the value from plus one and in the end add the total count.

How is this achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding the count of rows, and the sum of plusOnes together

```
SELECT COUNT(status) + SUM(plusOnes) FROM ...
```

Comment: Hey, thats easy! Didnt think it was gonna be just these few lines. Awesome!